# html elements only appear after space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I am using Javascript's `onkeyup` event to type the text entered into a `contenteditable` div into an input field.

When the user types into the div, they have the option to make the selected text bold or italic *(this is done by highlighting the desired text and clicking one of the buttons)*.

- If the user types 'hello' into the div and makes the text bold, it will display as `hello` in the input field (without `<br>` tags around the word).
- If the user types 'hello' into the div and makes the text bold, **then presses the spacebar**, it will display as `<b>hello</b>` in the input field.

How do I make it so that html tags automatically appear around the words without having to press the spacebar?

```
<form method="post">
<button type="button" id="bold"><b>B</b></button>
<button type="button" id="italic"><i>I</i></button>
<div id="post" style="border: 1px solid;" contenteditable></div>
<input type="text" name="hiddenTextarea" id="hiddenTextarea">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#bold').click(function() {
    document.execCommand('bold');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#italic').click(function() {
    document.execCommand('italic');
  });
});

var contentText = document.getElementById('post');
var hiddenInput = document.getElementById('hiddenTextarea');

// copy the text to input when the user writes in contentText div
contentText.onkeyup = function() {
    hiddenInput.value = this.innerHTML;  // 'this' is pointing to contentText
};
</script>
```

Here's a JsFiddle so you can see the issue for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/u6oeu9dL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input only gets updated on keyup, you should instead move the code that updates the input to a named function so that you can call it on keyup and on style button click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#bold').click(function() {
    document.execCommand('bold');
    updateInput();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#italic').click(function() {
    document.execCommand('italic');
    updateInput();
  });
});

var contentText = document.getElementById('post');
var hiddenInput = document.getElementById('hiddenTextarea');

function updateInput () {
  hiddenInput.value = contentText.innerHTML
}

// copy the text to input when the user writes in contentText div
contentText.onkeyup = updateInput;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u6oeu9dL/5/ *(simplified)*

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you inject a class name into div#post instead of execCommand

```
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
.italic { font-style: italic; }
```